# Google Analytics how to track search word with Angular filter by search key

Tags: angularjs, search, filter, google-analytics, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using **ng-repreat** to display a number of posts on my site and I also allow users to **filter the posts** by keying in any search phrase in a **search input box**. It is working fine but I don't know how to use google analytics to track what the users are searching for because the ***search term is not reflected on my URL***. (i.e. the URL is remains as ***domain-name/#!/content*** instead of changing to ***domain-name/#!/content?q=....+...*** ).

Not sure how to work around this. Really appreciate if you can point me to some resources. Thank you.

This is a simplified version of my code

```
<input ng-model="vm.searchKey" type="text" placeholder = "Search..." />
<div class="card" ng-repeat="post in vm.posts | filter: vm.searchKey">
    <a ng-href="#!/post/{{lifePost.post_id}}">
        <img class="card-img" src="{{post.img_url}}">
        <div class="card-img-overlay">
            <p class="card-text">{{post.tagline_grp}}</p>
            <h4 class="card-title">{{post.post_title}}</h4>
            <p class="card-text">{{post.post_excerpt}}</p>          
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: I figure out that i can use ng-change to do track the changes after 1s 

`<input ng-model="vm.searchKey" ng-model-options='{ debounce: 1000 }' ng-change='vm.trackSearchKey()' type="text" placeholder = "Search..." />`

and in my controller, send GA the words user type in to achieve what i want
`vm.trackSearchKey = function() {
        if (vm.searchKey) {
    ga('set', 'page', '/?q='+vm.searchKey);
    ga('send', 'pageview');
        }
    }
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out how to do this by enabling Site search Tracking for GA, detect the change event when user key in a search key and send a virtual pageview over.

HTML code

```
<input ng-model="vm.searchKey" ng-model-options='{ debounce: 1000 }' ng-change='vm.trackSearchKey()' type="text" placeholder = "Search..." />
<div class="card" ng-repeat="post in vm.posts | filter: vm.searchKey">
    <a ng-href="#!/post/{{lifePost.post_id}}">
        <img class="card-img" src="{{post.img_url}}">
        <div class="card-img-overlay">
            <p class="card-text">{{post.tagline_grp}}</p>
            <h4 class="card-title">{{post.post_title}}</h4>
            <p class="card-text">{{post.post_excerpt}}</p>          
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

JS code

```
vm.trackSearchKey = function() {
    if (vm.searchKey) {
        ga('set', 'page', '/?q='+vm.searchKey);
        ga('send', 'pageview');
    }
}
```